# Why there is no sbin folder in chroot jail path environment variable?

Tags: environment-variables, chroot

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 in a chroot jail and the value in `/etc/environment` is:

`PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"`.

However, whenever I login to the jail I find the PATH as follows:

`/home/username/bin:/home/username/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin`

The first two directories are added by `.profile` script but I cannot find where the rest come from. I want to have sbin directories as well. More specifically I would like to have `/home/username/bin:/home/username/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games` to be the PATH as in an standalone Ubuntu.

What I did so far is that I added `source /etc/environment` on the first line of `.profile` to resolve my issue. However I want to know why is that and what is a right solution and not a hack. Thanks.